# ArrayBuffer to TypedArray shows no content when accessed.

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port

I am running node.js and am reading bytes using the serialport module for javascript. I have a known message structure where some things are 1, 2, or x bytes long. 
I want to read each byte in to an element of an ArrayBuffer. Then when I have what I need I what to make a TypedArray and access these values.

If there is a better method then let me know.
My issue is that I can see the correct hex/base10 setting for each byte in the ArrayBuffer but when I create a TypedArray and try to access elements I get zero for all entries.

Bellow is some toy code I did for testing. Am I not understanding the correct use of these data structures?

```
var testArrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(8);
testArrayBuffer[0] = 0xFF;
testArrayBuffer[1] = 0xFF;
testArrayBuffer[2] = 0x00;
testArrayBuffer[3] = 0xFF;
testArrayBuffer[4] = 0x00;
testArrayBuffer[5] = 0x09;
testArrayBuffer[6] = 0x01;
testArrayBuffer[7] = 0x00;
console.log('testArrayBuffer.byteLength : ', testArrayBuffer.byteLength);
for(var i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    console.log('testArrayBuffer[', i, '].toString(16) : ', testArrayBuffer[i].toString(16));
    console.log('testArrayBuffer[', i, '].toString(10) : ', testArrayBuffer[i].toString(10));
    console.log('testArrayBuffer[', i, '].toString() : ', testArrayBuffer[i].toString());
    console.log('testArrayBuffer[', i, '] : ', testArrayBuffer[i]);
}
var testTypedArray = new Uint16Array(testArrayBuffer, 0, 4)
console.log('testTypedArray.length : ', testTypedArray.length);

for(var j=0; j<4; j++)
{
    console.log('testTypedArray[', j, '].toString(16) : ', testTypedArray[j].toString(16));
    console.log('testTypedArray[', j, '].toString(10) : ', testTypedArray[j].toString(10));
    console.log('testTypedArray[', j, '].toString() : ', testTypedArray[j].toString());
    console.log('testTypedArray[', j, '] : ', testTypedArray[j]);
}
```

This gives me the following output: (notice the typedarray is all zeros)

```
testArrayBuffer.byteLength :  8
testArrayBuffer[ 0 ].toString(16) :  ff
testArrayBuffer[ 0 ].toString(10) :  255
testArrayBuffer[ 0 ].toString() :  255
testArrayBuffer[ 0 ] :  255
testArrayBuffer[ 1 ].toString(16) :  ff
testArrayBuffer[ 1 ].toString(10) :  255
testArrayBuffer[ 1 ].toString() :  255
testArrayBuffer[ 1 ] :  255
testArrayBuffer[ 2 ].toString(16) :  0
testArrayBuffer[ 2 ].toString(10) :  0
testArrayBuffer[ 2 ].toString() :  0
testArrayBuffer[ 2 ] :  0
testArrayBuffer[ 3 ].toString(16) :  ff
testArrayBuffer[ 3 ].toString(10) :  255
testArrayBuffer[ 3 ].toString() :  255
testArrayBuffer[ 3 ] :  255
testArrayBuffer[ 4 ].toString(16) :  0
testArrayBuffer[ 4 ].toString(10) :  0
testArrayBuffer[ 4 ].toString() :  0
testArrayBuffer[ 4 ] :  0
testArrayBuffer[ 5 ].toString(16) :  9
testArrayBuffer[ 5 ].toString(10) :  9
testArrayBuffer[ 5 ].toString() :  9
testArrayBuffer[ 5 ] :  9
testArrayBuffer[ 6 ].toString(16) :  1
testArrayBuffer[ 6 ].toString(10) :  1
testArrayBuffer[ 6 ].toString() :  1
testArrayBuffer[ 6 ] :  1
testArrayBuffer[ 7 ].toString(16) :  0
testArrayBuffer[ 7 ].toString(10) :  0
testArrayBuffer[ 7 ].toString() :  0
testArrayBuffer[ 7 ] :  0
testTypedArray.length :  4
testTypedArray[ 0 ].toString(16) :  0
testTypedArray[ 0 ].toString(10) :  0
testTypedArray[ 0 ].toString() :  0
testTypedArray[ 0 ] :  0
testTypedArray[ 1 ].toString(16) :  0
testTypedArray[ 1 ].toString(10) :  0
testTypedArray[ 1 ].toString() :  0
testTypedArray[ 1 ] :  0
testTypedArray[ 2 ].toString(16) :  0
testTypedArray[ 2 ].toString(10) :  0
testTypedArray[ 2 ].toString() :  0
testTypedArray[ 2 ] :  0
testTypedArray[ 3 ].toString(16) :  0
testTypedArray[ 3 ].toString(10) :  0
testTypedArray[ 3 ].toString() :  0
testTypedArray[ 3 ] :  0
```

Let me know what you think.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As it [says on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer), you cannot directly manipulate the contents of an `ArrayBuffer`. So when you assign to `testArrayBuffer[0]`, you're not actually putting that in the buffer; you're just creating a property called `"0"` on the object. This is trivial to prove:

```js
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(1);
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(buf);
console.log(byteArray[0]);          // "0"
buf[0] = 42;
console.log(byteArray[0]);          // Still "0"
console.log(buf[0]);                // "42"
// Proof that "0" is a property on the object:
for (var n in buf) {
  console.log(n + " is " + buf[n]); // "0 is 42"
}
```

If you want to assign individual bytes, you do that with a `Uint8Array` (or an `Int8Array`).

Here's your code actually writing to the array buffer via a `Uint8Array`; as you can see, when you view it later as a `Uint16Array`, you see the bits were set and you see the different interpretation of them when viewing them as 16-bit words rather than 8-bit bytes:

```js
var testArrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(8);
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(testArrayBuffer);
byteArray[0] = 0xFF;
byteArray[1] = 0xFF;
byteArray[2] = 0x00;
byteArray[3] = 0xFF;
byteArray[4] = 0x00;
byteArray[5] = 0x09;
byteArray[6] = 0x01;
byteArray[7] = 0x00;
console.log('testArrayBuffer.byteLength : ', testArrayBuffer.byteLength);
for(var i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    console.log('byteArray[', i, '].toString(16) : ', byteArray[i].toString(16));
    console.log('byteArray[', i, '].toString(10) : ', byteArray[i].toString(10));
    console.log('byteArray[', i, '].toString() : ', byteArray[i].toString());
    console.log('byteArray[', i, '] : ', byteArray[i]);
}
var testTypedArray = new Uint16Array(testArrayBuffer, 0, 4)
console.log('testTypedArray.length : ', testTypedArray.length);

for(var j=0; j<4; j++)
{
    console.log('testTypedArray[', j, '].toString(16) : ', testTypedArray[j].toString(16));
    console.log('testTypedArray[', j, '].toString(10) : ', testTypedArray[j].toString(10));
    console.log('testTypedArray[', j, '].toString() : ', testTypedArray[j].toString());
    console.log('testTypedArray[', j, '] : ', testTypedArray[j]);
}
```